# No Sound on speakers or headphones. "Dummy Sound Output" Issue. It was working fine when I fresh installed. Then stopped working.

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

I am Using 18.04 Bionic Beaver LTS. Lenovo Ideapad Laptop. Dual booting Win 10 & Ubuntu.

Sound was working fine. I tried to better it by installing "Realtek Sound Drivers". Some errors came. I am new to Linux. Hence I quit in the middle. Now No sound.

Issue : No Sound on speakers or headphones. "**Dummy Sound Output**" Issue. It was working fine when I fresh installed. Then stopped working.

---

Alsa Diagnostics done.

Details on alsa here : http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=ccfda27af78831a617d14ecdd73413b59f211f78

---

Comment: I Use a Laptop. It has Built in speakers. Also use normal Headphones via 3.5mm audio jack.

Laptop : Lenovo Ideapad Y550
Graphics Card : Nvidia Geforce "series 100" 130M Graphicss Card.
Sound : In Windows I use Realtek Sound drivers.
OS: Ubuntu 18.04 & Windows 10 Dual Boot.

Comment: I tried to install " Linux driver (3.0) - Version 5.18rc8 " From http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false .

Comment: I tried

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload

Still have dummy sound issue.

Comment: Also When I check "Softwares & Updates" -> Additional Drivers, I get only this.

Screenshot link -> https://s22.postimg.cc/tpwxz1fap/Screenshot_from_2018-06-26_20-15-13.png

Many options seem to be missing.

Comment: Also note when I tried "sudo alsa force-reload" I got this.
    mahadevan@mdlap:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
    Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
    Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).

Comment: Also When I reload Synaptic Package Updater I get this in a dialogue box.

The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Screenshot -> https://s22.postimg.cc/8x3q296pd/Screenshot_from_2018-06-26_21-12-45.png

Comment: I did sudo aplay -l

and I got this output

mahadevan@mdlap:~$ sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

Comment: continuing....

mahadevan@mdlap:~$ sudo aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

mahadevan@mdlap:~$ find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd

mahadevan@mdlap:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-restricted-modules-`uname -r` linux-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-restricted-modules-4.15.0-23-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-restricted-modules-4.15.0-23-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-restricted-modules-4.15.0-23-generic'

Comment: I tried  the command in step #1C of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure still no avail on my problem. Dummy Output persists.